# C++ Header File Are Not Included - C++ Sample Application For Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, build, header-files

I know it is completely stupid question, but when I received a sample application supposed to run on Linux, I have got some .cpp files, with no .h files, even-though that inside the .cpp file there is a mentioning of some .h files, is it Ok? or the files are really missing and I should ask the supplier -which is a big company- to provide me with those missing .h files??

Sample of the files I have received:
The file name is: XXX.cpp

```
#include "XXX.h"

XXX::XXX(bool aEnableLogging /*= true*/) :
    abcd(aEnableLogging)
{
          //SOME CODE
}

XXX::~XXX()
{
    //SOME CODE
}

bool XXX::Run()
{
    //SOME CODE
}
.
.
.
```

Another question, can I easily write the .h files manually using .cpp? and what is the header file XXX.h for this XXX.cpp file for example??

PS. I am slightly new to C++, and I am trying to build this application using MS VS2010, can I do this? or I need clips or another Linuxy IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the header files.

You may be able to infer some of what is in them, but you will not be able to fully rewrite them yourself. For example, just by looking at this file we have no idea whether `XXX::Run()` should be public, private, or protected. It's also possible that there are inline functions/methods or even macros in the header file that don't appear in the source files.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, can you please do a very basic assumptions, and give me an example of a valid header file for this file please?

Comment: Let's suppose that this Run method is a public method in the interface for example

Comment: I could, but I fear that would lead you far down the wrong path. The correct response to this situation is to request the missing header files.

Comment: I see, my assumption is that I can infer the whole header file easily in my situation, because the sample application is only three files, with ~500 lines each.

Comment: Because requesting the headers from a big company may take a week to get a response!

Comment: You may be able to create one that works, but I can't really provide a good example given that there are often interdependencies I can't account for without all of the source files. It would be easier if I had all of the files at my disposal, but then we're talking about contract work and I'd have to charge you. ;)